# highcharts broken UI Chrome 40

Tags: google-chrome, highcharts

I'm running HighCharts (Simple Column Chart) and in IE the UI is ok and in place. However, in Chrome 40 the UI is broken in places. For example, the yAxes numbers are pushed onto the ticks, the legend text is merged with the color boxes and the highcharts logo is partially out of view. Is there any way to fix this?
IE:
[image]

Chrome 40:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem (Pheewwwh). Gave dir=ltr to the container DIV only. This fixed everything.